# yii2: Process selected rows of gridview not working - ajax post is empty

Tags: javascript, ajax, gridview, yii2

In my yii2-app I want to assign machines to a machine group. The number of machines makes it necessary that the user selects the machines using a checkbox column of a kartik-gridview (list of all machines) with sorting and filter (a normal multiselect formfield doesn't provide these funcionalities).

To process the selected rows of the grid I only found a solution using Javascript: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53777-gridview-get-selected-colum/

I implemented this in my button:

```
<?= Html::button(yii::t('app', 'Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 
        'onclick' => "var keys = $('#w0.grid-view').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');"
                    . "$.ajax({"
                    . "type: 'POST',"
                    . "url: 'http://localhost:8080/eddb1/frontend/web/index.php?r=machine-group/test',"
                    . "dataType: 'json',"
                    . "data: {keylist: keys}});"]) ?>
```

As you can see, I had to use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` because with `$.post` the url didn't work and I allways got **404 not found**-error.

The problem is, that the ajax-post is allways empty. Following the controller-code to echo the post-request:

```
public function actionTest()
{
        echo var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post());
        die();
}
```

I also tried it with

```
echo var_dump($_POST);
```

same result.
What am I doing wrong here? Is there any posibility to process the selected rows without Javascript? - I tried to put the gridview inside of **ActiveForm**-Tags and use the normal **submittButton** but no post-request is sent.

Please any help, got stuck here for 2 days now...thx!!!

PS.: that's the gridview-code:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        'company_name',
        'identifier',
        'licenceplate',
        'serial_number',
        'type_name',
        'class_name',
        'manufacturer',
        'model_name',
        'variant_name',
    ],
    'persistResize' => true,
    'showPageSummary' => false,
    'pjax' => true,
    'panel' => [
       'before' => ''
    ],
    'toolbar' => [
        '{export}',
        '{toggleData}'
    ]
]);  
?>
```

Comment: Use `console.debug()` in firefox/chrome to dump your `keys` var, make sure there is actually something in it. I suspect it will be empty.

Comment: it's empty...but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: The problem is, that "getSelectedRows" returns the primary keys of a table based model. My dataprovider and searchmodel for the gridview is based on a MySQL-View without primary keys, so the function allways returned an empty keys-array.

Had to use primaryKey-Function to set a PK in my view-model, overwrite my searchmodel with GII and everything is running fine (don't forget to declare your PK as an array, even if it is a single attribute).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your selector to get to the data is wrong, you might want to try something like:

```
var keys = $(this).parents('.gridview').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

This has the added advantage that it is not linked to a changing identifier. the `w0`-part is created by a counter in the `Widget`-functionality and can change if you happen to have other widgets before the `GridView`. So I would try to avoid matching on ID in this case.

Comment: Hi Blizz, the selector I used seems to be right. With your code I allways get an error: "TypeError: data is undefined". I tried it with different parents...same error. This is the HTML-Tag for the grid: <div id="w0" class="grid-view" data-krajee-grid="kvGridInit_26c63261">. The original code runs thru but the ajax-post is allways empty. Any other ideas???

Comment: The selector is wrong... You are selecting on an ID but include a class in the name. You either select on ID or on class. Both doesn't work. It's looking for an element with id `w0.grid-view` which doesn't exist, hence the remark about `data()` not existing as a consequence.

Comment: Hi Blizz, I don't know if I expressed myself the wrong way: if I use w0.grid-view or only w0 the result is the same: the code runs through but the response of my controller is empty (and so the ajax-post is empty). Your code above doesn't work: "TypeError: data is undefined"

Comment: First we need the result of your `yiiGridView('getSelectedRows')`-call to return data. My gut tells me it has something to do with the selector, but I could be off. If you debug output the selector alone (`$('#w0')`), does that yield the correct `div`?